# How to impersonate JS enabled browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, scripting

I need to download a webpage using script (PHP, Python, Bash) and not using GUI browser. The problem is the web page checks up front is it deals with JS enabled browser. So all I got using naive downloading from given URL is initial page (in this case I think about Coursera courses page: http://pastebin.com/4tJJRMTu).

How can I download the "real" content using script? So far I can think about such solutions (some crazy ones):

- figuring out what JS on startup pages does, and mimic this in my script, probably loading another page
- scan network traffic using Wireshark and find a pattern that request for page `ABC1.html` ends up with fetching page `ABC1body.html`
- instead of native (for given language) download feature launch external browser to just download the page (`exec Firefox --dump http://foo.bar/x.html` -- I am making this up, I even don't know if there is a browser with scripting capability).

And other ideas? I would be grateful for tested ones.

*Dropping script and instead writing a browser plugin is also one of the options, but since I already put some time to write the scripts for now it seems quicker to fix them, instead writing them from scratch.*

Comment: check out http://phantomjs.org/ - it let's you do just that.

Comment: @JustinBicknell, it falls into "do it from scratch" category, because it would solve downloading (I think!) but I would have the rest of my script to rewrite into JS.

Comment: You could always pass the phantomjs output to your previously written scripts - either though a http post, or dropping the file onto the filesystem your code resides

Comment: @JustinBicknell, ok, looks OK, I'll just wait a bit more for other ideas, if nothing appears, I will go with PhantomJS, thank you.

Comment: why can't you use a browser for this task?

Comment: @dandavis, for what task? My script is a "tad" longer than just accessing web page -- this is just a start. Of course I can use web browser -- see my last remark in question.

Comment: my point is just that urls can launch a browser from the shell, and other scripts can close it by pid, and in the middle, the browser via tampermonkey can do anything phantom does and a whole lot more...

Comment: @dandavis. it seems to me a bit of overkill (and fragile workflow), but thank you for the hint about tampermonkey, I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It is essentially a headless browser, mimicking all functionality.

Using node and the phantomjs module you can download a page and have full control over it, including complete access to the JavaScript.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://www.phantomjs.org/';
page.open(url, function (status) {
    //Page is loaded!
    phantom.exit();
});
```